# Substitution $\partial_\mu \to D_\mu \equiv \partial_\mu + ieA_\mu$ allows the introduction of electromagnetic interactions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gauge-theory, dirac-equation, spinors

I want to show that the substitution $\partial_u \to D_\mu \equiv \partial_\mu + ieA_\mu$, or equivalently $p_\mu \to p_\mu - eA_\mu$ allows the introduction of electromagnetic interactions. Here $e$ is the electric charge of the particle in question $($$e=-|e|$ for an electron$)$, and $A^\mu = (\Phi, \vec{A})$ is the vector potential. By converting the Dirac equation in the form$$[\vec{\alpha} \cdot (\vec{p} - e\vec{A}) + \beta m]\psi = (E - e\Phi)\psi$$to a second-order equation, and taking the low-energy limit, show that the interaction with the electromagnetic field gives rise to a change in energy in the presence of a magnetic field $\vec{B} = \nabla \times \vec{A}$ of the form$$\Delta E = -{{e}\over{2m}}\vec{\sigma} \cdot \vec{B}$$and hence implies a value of $g=2$ for the electron's magnetic moment $\vec{\mu}$ defined in terms of its spin $S$ as$$\vec{u} = g\left({e\over{2m}}\right)\vec{S}.$$Progress so far: The Dirac equation is $$(i\gamma^\mu D_\mu - m)\psi = (i\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu + ieA_\mu) - m)\psi = 0.$$If we take $\gamma^0 = \beta$, $\gamma^i = \beta\alpha_i$, $\partial_\mu = (\partial_i, \nabla)$, and $A_\mu = (\Phi, -{\bf A})$ then we can write this as $$[i\beta(\partial_t + ie\Phi) + i\beta\alpha \cdot (\nabla - ie{\bf A}) - m]\psi = 0$$or, since $\beta^2 = 1$,$$[i(\partial_t + ie\Phi) + i\alpha \cdot (\nabla - ie{\bf A}) - m\beta]\psi = 0.$$I tried some things after this, but they didn't work out. Can anyone give me a step in the right direction?

Comment: now you have an interaction term between the electromagnetic potential $A$ and the spinor $\psi$

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can I ee explicitly that the substitution is equivalent to $p_\mu \to p_\mu - eA_\mu$?

Comment: I edited the question to fit the rules, hopefully. Can someone reopen the thread?